# How do I compare the first element (string) of a pair in a pair vector with another string?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to implement what I've learned about `std::vector` to solve a problem. User is going to input a list of animal names (not specified how many) and I need to record the animal names and their occurrences in the user input. At first, I tried using an array, but as it's static, I turned to `std::vector`. Again, at first, I tried using two `std::vector`, one with type `int` and the other with type `string` to store the animal names and the amount of occurrences. However, it seems a bit hard to sort both vectors later and a `std::vector` with a `pair` type sounds better in my mind. And now, I'm stuck with this code below with errors I don't quite understand:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int position(vector< pair<string, int> > myList, string animalName) {
    int pos;
    for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) if (animalName.compare(myList[i].first) == 0) pos = i;
    return pos;
}

int main() {
    int Q;
    cin >> Q;

    vector< pair<string, int> > zooPair;
    string animal;

    for (int i = 0; i < Q; i++){
        cin >> animal;
        if (find_if(zooPair.begin(), zooPair.end(), animal.compare(zooPair.first) == 0) == zooPair.end())
            zooPair.emplace_back(animal, 1);
        else
            zooPair[position(zooPair, animal)].second += 1;
    }

    sort(zooPair.begin(), zooPair.end());

    for (vector< pair<string, int> >::iterator it = zooList.begin(); it != zooList.end(); it++)
        cout << *it;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to give a comparator to sort

Comment: @gsamaras What does 'comparator' mean?

Comment: It tells sort how to compare the elements of the vector, so that it can order them.

Comment: @gsamaras http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/ I see! So I need to place `zooPair.first` as a comparator? It will automatically sort it in an ascending order, right?

Comment: Wealthy I would just provide a comparator who would compare the first field, so I think we say the same. That's different than the accepted answer now from Klaus, but since you are happy with it, then I am happy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply should use `std::map` as the container type, because it already sorts, have a easy to use access interface with operator[]. Here we create a `std::map` with your animal and the number of them in your zoo.

Example:

```
int main() {
    int Q;
    std::cout << "Enter number of entries" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> Q;

    std::map<std::string, int> zoo;

    std::string animal;

    for (int i = 0; i < Q; i++){
        std::cout << "Enter animal" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> animal;
        zoo[animal]++;
    }

    for ( auto& it: zoo )
    {
        std::cout << it.first << " " << it.second << std::endl;
    }


    return 0; 
}
```

As you see, there is no need for an additional sort as a map is always sorted for the first part, named the "key", of every entry.

The same with `std::vector`. Remark that you have to give operators for sort and find!

Full example:

```
struct SortableElements: public std::pair< std::string, int >
{
    // forward construction 
    using std::pair<std::string, int>::pair;

    // use for sort: 
    bool operator < (const SortableElements& e2 ) const
    {
        return first < e2.first;
    }

    // use for find: 
    bool operator == ( const std::string& e2 ) const
    {
        return first == e2;
    }
};



int main() 
{   
    std::vector< SortableElements > zoo;

    int Q;
    std::cout << "Enter number of entries" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> Q;

    std::string animal;

    for (int i = 0; i < Q; i++){
        std::cout << "Enter animal" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> animal;

        auto it = std::find( zoo.begin(), zoo.end(), animal);
        if ( it != zoo.end())
        {
            it->second++;
        }
        else
        {
            zoo.emplace_back( animal, 1 );
        }
    }

    // sort:
    std::sort(zoo.begin(), zoo.end());

    for ( auto& it: zoo )
    {
        std::cout << it.first << " " << it.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do `zoo[animal]++` and `auto& it: zoo` mean?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer: Please read the documentation for std::map. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/ And for the loop: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: I see, thank you! Does it automatically initialise the second element (the `int`) of the entries as 0 if the key I insert creates a new entry? Also, what does `auto& it: zoo` mean? After reading some other posts, it seems like `auto&` automatically infers the type of the item next to it. But what does the `: zoo` do then?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer: Sorry, did you read about "range based for". The link is already there!

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice the edit, but I've read your link and found it quite confusing. So I tried this link too (as you've given me the name): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/range-based-loop-c/. I understand what `auto` does now and the other non-forwarding accesses now, but what does the `&` mean in your code? It seems like there's `auto&&` , though, in the link you provided. However, I don't quite understand what 'forwarding reference' meant. Should I not be bothered by that? What if I don't use `&` in your code above? Can I achieve the same results with access by value?

Comment: Also, does `std::map` initialise a mapped value of `0` when the type is `int` and it's not defined in a new entry?

Comment: If you use `auto` your loop will take a copy on each element in the loop and if you use `auto&` you get a reference to the elelemnt in the vector. As you don't need a copy a reference is what you want. Read about reference in general...

Comment: @WealthyPlayer: Yes! But hey, please read!!!! In the given link you will find the access operator `operator[]()` for std::map. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5B%5D/ I can't you explain every line of the code in detail. All the links to the references are given here! Would be nice to see that you accept the answer... :-)

Comment: But I did read about `operator[]()` for `std::map`. It didn't say that it would initialise the content of non-assigned mapped value of `int` as `0`. I guess I was asking for reassurance. And I've also read access my pointer, reference and value just now. I guess I quite understand now, but is it correct to say that I can also achieve the same result if I access it by value?

Comment: @WealthyPlayer If I read the link I gave I find: "
If k does not match the key of any element in the container, the function inserts a new element with that key and returns a reference to its mapped value. Notice that this always increases the container size by one, even if no mapped value is assigned to the element (the element is constructed using its default constructor)." Quite clear! If element is not in the container, it creates a new one with default constructor. Default construct for int is 0. :-)

Comment: I understood that it will insert a new element with that key, but not so much on the 'returns a reference to its mapped value' part. I also understand the increasing container size by one part.
EDIT: Ah I see, I did not know that the default constructor for `int` is 0, thanks for reassuring me.

Comment: Could you please give me a link about `bool operator << (const SortableElement& e2) const` for reading?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183410/discussion-between-klaus-and-wealthy-player).